# how to access all the property values from a class in the rows of a tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am a brand new swift coder working on my first app.

I have two separate arrays - 1 contains all of the property names for a class and the other array contains all of the values for those properties.

Those two arrays are used to populate a tableView (1 column UILabel and the other column being a textView) such that each row represents 1 property of the class.

I want to be able to edit the values in each row and save them to CoreData.

Currently I have a switch command and individual case statements based upon the value of the index path.row which lets the app determine which textview is being edited and what it's corresponding property is.

But this is very cumbersome if I have lots of properties to have an individual case for all of those options - it could be dozens depending on how many properties I choose to have.

I was thinking I could do something like:

```
   propertyArray = ["name","Sex",Type"]
   valueArray = [self.animal.name, self.animal.sex, self.animal.type]  

   for x in (1...3) (the 3 being the total number of properties)

     switch indexPath.row

         case x

            self.animal.(propertyArray[x]) = textView.text
```

obviously I'm not using all the full syntax here - but just giving you the idea of my logic.  but that syntax in the last statement doesn't work at all as the system is looking for the actual property name after the period and isn't able to accept a substitute variable it doesn't seem like.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: you can create an array of a `Class` instances that contains the name and value and use it to populate your tableview. since `Class` instances are references type, as long as you keep a reference to the `Class` instance inside your cell, you can assign value to its property.

Comment: Ugh, I'm sorry to be dense, but that explanation is mostly lost on me.  what are 'instances' of a class?  that will give me a start on researching this further - just looking for the logical understanding of what that means.

Comment: I did some reading and I think I already have the array of class instances. I have 2 screens.  1 screen shows a tableview generated from an array of the objects that are part of that class.  Then in clicking a row from that tableview, it goes to another screen that shows a detail view of all of the properties only for that particular instance of the class.My problem comes when I click a row for the purpose of editing the textfield in that row... when I click row 2 for example, how do i code it such that the program knows that row 2 is the animalType property and not the animal name property?

Comment: so is there a way I can put the properties themselves into an array?  i.e. if a class has properties:  class.a, class.b, class.c, class.d - how do I get a, b, c, d into an array in a way that it can be used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to do some research on Reflection:

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: classInstance)
```

Here's a very simple example that may help:

```
class MyClass: UIView {
    var myColor: UIColor = .blue
    var myName: String = "MyName"
    var myAge: Int = 21
    var myPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200)
}

class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let myClass = MyClass()

        // list the properties, types and values
        listProperties(for: myClass)

        // change some values
        myClass.myColor = .red
        myClass.myName = "You know who I am"
        myClass.myAge = 42
        myClass.myPoint = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
        
        print()
        print("Properties after changes:")
        print()

        // list the properties, types and values
        listProperties(for: myClass)
        
    }

    func listProperties(for classInstance: Any) -> Void {

        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: classInstance)
        
        for child in mirror.children {
            print("Property name: ", child.label)
            print("Property type: ", type(of: child.value))
            print("Property value:", child.value)
            print()
        }

    }
    
}
```

Debug console output:

```
Property name:  Optional("myColor")
Property type:  UICachedDeviceRGBColor
Property value: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1

Property name:  Optional("myName")
Property type:  String
Property value: MyName

Property name:  Optional("myAge")
Property type:  Int
Property value: 21

Property name:  Optional("myPoint")
Property type:  CGPoint
Property value: (100.0, 200.0)


Properties after changes:

Property name:  Optional("myColor")
Property type:  UICachedDeviceRGBColor
Property value: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1

Property name:  Optional("myName")
Property type:  String
Property value: You know who I am

Property name:  Optional("myAge")
Property type:  Int
Property value: 42

Property name:  Optional("myPoint")
Property type:  CGPoint
Property value: (50.0, 50.0)
```

Comment: Ah!  I posted this question in another place and the person also posted an example using mirror but didn't clue me in that it was a key piece in the equation.  This is very helpful and I will indeed begin researching that!

Comment: and I'm looking at your example a bit more closely -and yet, something along these lines is exactly what I need. you rock!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have your class conform to the [`Encodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types), which would allow you to serialize it to a JSON object. More simply, assuming you don't have a ton of properties on the object, you could create a function that returns a dictionary of the property names and their values, as a `[String:Any]`.

So, your class would look something like this:

```swift
class Animal {
    var name: String
    var sex: Sex
    var type: Type

    init(name: String, sex: Sex, type: Type) {
        self.name = name
        self.sex  = sex
        self.type = type
    }

    func toDict() -> [String: Any] {
        return [
            "name": self.name,
            "sex": self.sex,
            "type": self.type
        ]
    }
}
```

When we have a dictionary representation of our object, we can easily convert both the dictionary's keys and values to arrays, via `Array(self.animal.toDict().keys)` or `Array(self.animal.toDict().values)` respectively. So, in your UITableView, you could do something like this:

```swift
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var animal: Animal

    init(animal: Animal) {
        self.animal = animal
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension SomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let propertyNames = Array(self.animal.toDict().keys)
        return propertyNames.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "propertyCell", for: indexPath) as! PropertyCell

        let propertyName = Array(self.animal.toDict().keys)[indexPath.row]
        cell.propertyNameTextView.text = propertyName

        let propertyValue = Array(self.animal.toDict().values)[indexPath.row]
        let propertyValueString: String!
        if (propertyValue is String) {
            propertyValueString = propertyValue
        } else {
            //The following would require your Sex and Type enums to have associated values of the String type
            if let sex = propertyValue as? Sex {
                propertyValueString = sex.rawValue
            } else if let type = propertyValue as? Type {
                propertyValueString = type.rawValue
            }
        }
        cell.propertyValueTextView.text = propertyValueString
       
        return cell
    }
}
```

P.S. sorry if this code seems a bit off. I've been doing a lot more programming in Dart rather than Swift lately :)

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you for taking the time to help me with this!!

Comment: No problem, legend